# Search tree with canonical layout

Tags: c#, algorithm, data-structures

I'm looking for a search tree that can be organized in a canonical form.

Please excuse me if I'm using the term "canonical" wrong here. What I mean is that; given a set of items to be stored in the tree, the resulting node structure will be the same no matter what operations were made to make those items to end up in there.

I don't need a structure that *always* provide this feature; it is sufficient if there would be a "make it canonical please"-feature.

I've currently created a basic AVL tree implementation in C#.

When I add seven items (1-7) to it, by appending them, I end up with the following nodes:

```
              4
           /     \
        2          6
      /   \      /   \
    1      3    5     7
```

If I instead first add items `1, 2, 0, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 7`, by appending them, and then remove those two zeroes I end up with the following nodes instead:

```
           3
         /   \
        2     5
       /    /   \
      1    4     7      
                /
               6
```

Enumerating the items in those two trees yield the same expected result. But the node structure differ, which is what I'd like to avoid.

I understand that I could implement the "please make it canonical"-feature by just creating a new tree from scratch. But that doesn't scale.

I'd also be happy to trade the canonical property for speed in cases when getting to the canonical form would require too much effort.

---

**Why "canonical"?**

I'm pursuing an idea where I'm going to chunk up the tree using a content-based chunking algorithm (TTTD) and then store those chunks in an immutable blob store.

With this approach some child nodes would be inline: stored in the same chunk as the parent. Other nodes would be external: referenced by a content-based address (SHA-1 hash).

When two subtrees have the same content (incl. structure) they would have the same address. This property is useful for many reasons; including:

- efficiently computing the difference between two subtrees.
- caching.
- synchronization.

Comment: How could the program know which "canonical" tree structure it is you wanted for any given set of data? Take for example some tree of 100 random numbers between 1-1000 added in a random. Say it you remove a random 50 elements. How could the program possibly know you wanted the node structure of those 50 leftover nodes added in sorted order? Unless you knew exactly what possible sets of data you had and kept each variation of tree in memory (don't do that) I don't think you can accomplish this without remaking the tree each time.

Comment: More importantly why do you care about node structure? You said yourself they function the same way. Are you displaying the tree structure in some UI?

Comment: So assuming you are having this requirement for UI, i.e. given a set of items the user only sees a single tree structure, there are two ways you could possibly do this. You could store the elements in a list and generate the tree specifically for the ui. This isn't great for large sets of items, and also if the user is adding/removing in real time that would probably be slow. Another option is to store every set the user has seen in memory, this could be extremely costly the more distinct sets the user creates, but could potentially work. Overall I still think the reasonable answer is don't

Comment: @GordonAllocman  and @HenkHolterman; please see my update for the *why?*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a trie, which has a maximum update and search time of the bit-length of your keys, or you can use [A. Andersson and Th. Ottmann. "Faster Uniquely Represented Dictionaries"](http://user.it.uu.se/~arnea/abs/fastun.html), which has a maximum update and search time of \Theta(n^{1/3}).

Comment: Ah, the same Arne after whom the AA trees are named! :-) Thanks for linking the paper.